# Unix Find Command Ignoring Missing File or Directory

Tags: bash, macos, unix, terminal

I have this little command that delete all files within `~/Library/Cache`, `~/Library/Logs`, `/Library/Cache` and `/Library/Logs` directories but sometimes, one or more directories are missing and the `rm -rf` command is not execute.

```
sudo find ~/Library/Caches ~/Library/Logs /Library/Caches /Library/Logs -mindepth 1 -type f -exec rm -rf {}+
```

I wanted the command to ignore missing directories and just execute the command to the files that are found.

Comment: A) If the directory is already missing, what will `rm -rf` accomplish? B) if it really is missing, it will not be reported by find. It's quite likely that you have read access to the directory but not write.

Comment: A) `rm -rf` command ignores missing file/directory. B) The `find` command will report missing file or directory. Try executing `find /missing-directories` and you'll see `find: /missing-directories: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Timir if you see `find` command reporting `find: /missing-directories: No such file or directory` after executing `find /missing-directories`, please upvote my question :)

Comment: Put `2>/dev/null` at the end to send error messages to `/dev/null`. Also put a space between `{}` and `+`.

Comment: @yaeykay There's nothing to be done by `rm -rf` when `/missing-directories` doesn't exist. Redirect error messages to `/dev/null` as suggested above.

Comment: @Kusalananda please make your commend an answer so I can make this question answered. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue here is that you are annoyed with seeing the error message about missing directories.

You may redirect the standard error stream to `/dev/null` to ignore errors:

```
sudo find ~/Library/Caches ~/Library/Logs \
           /Library/Caches  /Library/Logs \
           -mindepth 1 -type f -exec rm -rf {} + 2>/dev/null
```

Also note that `-mindepth 1` is not needed here, and that some `find` implementations have `-delete`:

```
sudo find ~/Library/Caches ~/Library/Logs \
           /Library/Caches  /Library/Logs \
           -type f -delete 2>/dev/null
```

Or, with a shell that understands brace expansions:

```
sudo find {~,}/Library/{Logs,Caches} -type f -delete 2>/dev/null
```